# Circle contour in space (threejs) (3D)

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

How to delete this line in this fugure http://joxi.ru/gmvl7YwT7Eg3Aa? I need only contour

```
const intersection = (a, b, c, heightC) => {
    return (u, v) => {
        const height = heightC || c;
        const size = 5;

        u = u * height;
        v = 2 * v * Math.PI;

        const x = a * size * Math.sqrt(u) * Math.cos(v);
        const y = c;
        const z = b * size * Math.sqrt(u) * Math.sin(v);

        return new Three.Vector3(x, y, z);
    }
}

export const projectionIntersection = (a, b, heightC) => {
    const geom = new Three.ParametricGeometry(intersection(a, b, 1, heightC), 1, 25);
    const math = new Three.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x00FF00, wireframe: true });
    const mesh = new Three.Mesh(geom, math);

    return mesh;
}
```

Who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parametric geometry as a mesh will create faces, which means creating linkages between the center and each point along the edge. If you want just a line strip to draw a circle, take a look at [Line Object](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/objects/Line). It looks like you can do what you're doing already, just pushing the Vector3 you create to the vertices of geometry and making a Line out of it.

Comment: I got this results: joxi.ru/Dr8PN3kUxg8zr6 :D I am doing next (it's a hotfix): gist.github.com/DimaDaxDadeco/25b1cb4a9012b8721cebd939a6ab8b‌​81 How i can draw only circle?)

Comment: you're pushing the vertices wrong. Just do for(var theta = 0; theta < Math.PI*2; theta += Math.PI*2/16)push(new Vector3(Math.cos(theta),0,Math.sin(theta)).multiplyScalar(radius);

to get that result, you must interleaving center points. That's wrong. Show your code

Comment: Check my comment on the gist and then mark as answered

Comment: Sorry for late answer, i was ill:( i need the figure (ellipse) like i   created with mech, but your ex do it another ellipse.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You need to provide a picture or a sketch of a) what you want b) what the problem with my proposed solution is

Answer (score 1):

Cheap and rough solution with a circle:

```
var circleGeom = new THREE.CircleGeometry(1, 32);
circleGeom.vertices.shift();
circleGeom.vertices.push(circleGeom.vertices[0].clone());
var circle = new THREE.Line(circleGeom, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: "yellow"}));
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/tuohfuy0/) example r85